# Meddling with variable variables in PHP

Tags: php, loops, variables

I am trying to use variable variables. By using `$type` in a foreach loop, I would like to get the value of `$week['one']` and `$month['one']`.

```
    $types = array(
        'week',
        'month'
    );

    $week = array(
        'one' => 1.2,
        'two' => 0.13,
    );

    $month = array(
        'one' => 1.2,
        'two' => 0.13,
    );
```

Methods I've tried without success:

```
    <?php foreach ($types as $type): ?>
            <?= $$type['one']; ?><br />
            <?= $$type['two']; ?><br />
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach ($types as $type): ?>
            <?= ${$type}['one']; ?><br />
            <?= ${$type}['two']; ?><br />
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach ($types as $type): ?>
            <?= $($type)['one']; ?><br />
            <?= $($type)['two']; ?><br />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Everything seems to resul in syntax errors. Am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.variable.php#50912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this variant:

```
<?php foreach ($types as $type): ?>
        <?= ${$type}['one']; ?><br />
        <?= ${$type}['two']; ?><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Check it here: https://3v4l.org/H7Pn7.

Comment: What PHP version does this require. It doesn't seem to work for me. And for the record... I wasn't the one downvoting :)

Comment: Check again, please, I've added a link. First answer was only for >= 7.
Actually, you have this correct variant.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I had a typo :) I used `${$type}'week']`